# The step counter sensor is not working for my app. Could you please tell me what the problem is? I have been trying to debug this for days now

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-sensors

TYPE_STEP_COUNTER is not working with this code. Could anyone please tell me what is wrong.
My min sdk is 19 and target sdk is 30. I have also tried using TYPE_STEP_COUNTER instead number of 19 but it still does not work. Please help!!

I have been trying to debug this for hours now. I am using pixel 3 to test this and I see that the required sensor is here but for some reason this is not working.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener, View.OnClickListener {

    var running = false
    private var sensorManager: SensorManager? = null
    lateinit var sharebutton: Button
    lateinit var goalnum: Button
    lateinit var et: EditText
    lateinit var tv: EditText
    lateinit var progress: ProgressBar
    lateinit var step2: EditText
    var steps=0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout)
        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        sharebutton = findViewById(R.id.share) as Button
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv) as EditText
        sharebutton.setOnClickListener(this)
        goalnum = findViewById(R.id.goalnum) as Button
        goalnum.setOnClickListener(this)
        val circularProgressBar = findViewById<CircularProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
        val toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tbar) as Toolbar?
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        getSupportActionBar()?.setTitle("");

        //manualInc()


    }


    override fun onResume() {
        //manualInc()
        Toast.makeText(this, "I am in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        super.onResume()
        running = true;
        var StepSensor = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(19)
        if (StepSensor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Step Counter Sensor !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            sensorManager?.registerListener(this, StepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
        }

    }

    fun manualInc(){
        steps =100
        var step2 = tv.getText().toString().toInt()
        var steps3 = (step2 - steps)
        tv_steps.setText("" + steps.toInt())
        if (steps3 > 0) {
            tv_steps2.setText("" + (steps3).toInt());
        } else {
            tv_steps2.setText("Goal Reached!");
        }
        val currentsteps = step2 - steps.toInt()
        progressBar.apply{
            setProgressWithAnimation(currentsteps.toFloat())
        }
        if(steps> step2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GOAL REACHED!!! Amazing job!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        running = true;
        var StepSensor = sensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(19)
        if (StepSensor == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Step Counter Sensor !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            sensorManager?.registerListener(this, StepSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI)
        }

    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when (view?.id) {
            R.id.goalnum -> {
                var goalcount = tv.getText().toString().toDouble()
                userinput.setText("" + goalcount.toInt())
                Toast.makeText(this, "Great goal!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            R.id.share -> {
                val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                    var goalcount = tv.getText().toString().toInt()
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    putExtra(
                            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            "I am on my way to reaching my goal of " + goalcount + " daily steps! Join me on Step Counter and Tracker"
                    )
                    type = "text/plain"
                }
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(p0: Sensor?, p1: Int) {
    }

    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I am i", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        if (running) {
            val steps = (event.values[0])
            var step2 = tv.getText().toString().toInt()
            var steps3 = (step2 - steps)
            tv_steps.setText("" + steps.toInt())
            if (steps3 > 0) {
                tv_steps2.setText("" + (steps3).toInt());
            } else {
                tv_steps2.setText("Goal Reached!");
            }
            val currentsteps = step2 - steps.toInt()
            progressBar.apply{
                setProgressWithAnimation(currentsteps.toFloat())
            }
            if(steps> step2) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "GOAL REACHED!!! Amazing job!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }}}



    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle presses on the action bar menu items
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_one -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                finishAffinity();
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.action_two -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, ExerciseHistory::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            R.id.action_three -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, ViewListContents::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.action_four -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, StepHistory::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            R.id.action_five -> {
                val intent = Intent(this, Help::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Please leave feedback!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```